# Calculate variables using time

Tags: php, html, laravel

I'm trying to get data coming from through the bank I believe the problem lies in not only having numbers but possessing ":"

The function is triggered via a link in the view with information from id through the get and hidden post with information of the id of the user who made the request.

In the database I have the time stored as follows hours:minutes:seconds

```
public function aprovar(Request $request, $id)
{
  $iduser = $request->input('colaboradores');
  DB::table('solicitacoes_banco')->where('idsolicitacao', $id)->update(['status_solicitacao' => '1']);

  $usuario = DB::select('select * from users where id = :id', ['id' => $iduser]);
  $solicitacoes = DB::select('select * from solicitacoes_banco where idsolicitacao = :id', ['id' => $id]);
  foreach($solicitacoes as $solicitacao) {}
  foreach($usuario as $usuario) {}

  $tiposolicitacao = $solicitacao->tiposolicitacao;
  $horasolicitacao = $solicitacao->horasolicitacao;

  if ($tiposolicitacao == "saida") {

      $horariocorreto = "17:30";
      if ($horasolicitacao < $horariocorreto) {
          $horaretirar = $horariocorreto - $horasolicitacao;

          $banco_usuario = $usuario->quant_banco;

          $desconto = $banco_usuario - $horaretirar;

          DB::table('users')->where('id', $iduser)->update(['quant_banco' => $desconto]);
      }

  }
  elseif($tiposolicitacao == 'entrada') {

      $horariocorreto = "08:30";

  }
  elseif($tiposolicitacao == 'folga') {

  }

  return redirect('rh/solicitacao');
}
```

Comment: It makes absolutely no sense to try and perform math operations on values like `17:30`. _“In the database I have the time stored as follows hours:minutes:seconds”_ - do you mean in text form? Then go and fix that first. Storing only the number of seconds probably makes most sense, if you want to do calculations with the value.

Comment: in the database is in the form of time. Ex.: 05:35:00

Comment: I need to make sure that the result of the calculation is 00:30, in the database the value 05:35:00 becomes 05:05:00

I will not use seconds.

Comment: Well then you would have to split `05:35:00` into its parts first, and then do the math using those. Of course you will have to take care of “overflows” yourself then (like when you subtract 50 minutes _from_ 15 minutes.) Storing the values as seconds only makes this a lot easier of course. You use the seconds to perform the math, and only _format_ them as hh:mm:ss when you show the value to the user.

Answer (score 0):

Store the variables in time format if you need to show that format most of the time, but if calculations must be made maybe a number of seconds since midnight might be better.

If you stick with the Datetime format or even a string you can add a [mutator](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-mutators) function that will transform your entry when fetching it.
In your "solicitacoes_banco" model add this function (and the same one in the "usuario" model too called getQuantBancoAttribute):

```
public function getHorasolicitacaoAttribute($time)
{
    return \Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('H:i:s', $time);
}
```

You will then have a Carbon object that you can [modify and compare easily](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/).

For example you could write :

```
$horaretirar = $horariocorreto->diffInMinutes($horasolicitacao);
```

And you would have the number of minutes between them. There are many other useful functions in the Carbon library.

Comment: +1 for using the Carbon library. @Noscin you will definitely want to use Carbon instead of trying to calculate the difference yourself.

Comment: I think if I transform these values into integers, it would be easier to calculate, then I just put the points for the user to see. what do you think? Ex: 17:30 will come 1730.

Comment: @Noscin I think that would be a bad idea even though you could make it work by taking into account in your calculation that an hour is 100 minutes. It's just not practical.
If you don't want to use Carbon then just create two helper functions :
One that transforms the time into seconds (17:30 => 63000), and one that goes the other way (50000 => 13:53:20).

Comment: @Noscin why don't you want to use Carbon?? It is a much better solution than what you're talking about...plus it's included in Laravel anyway

Comment: Do you still need help @Noscin or do you have your answer ?